# Declare member function only for specific template instantiation of class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is it possible to declare a member function only for specific template instantiations of a class? This is why I want to do it:

```
// Polynomial<N> is a polynomial of degree N
template<int N>
class Polynomial {
public:
    //... various shared methods e.g...
    double eval(double x) const;
    Polynomial<N-1> derivative() const;
    Polynomial<N+1> integralFrom(double x0) const;
    // ... various shared operators etc.

    double zero() const; // only want Polynomial<1> to support this
    // only want Polynomial<2> and Polynomial<1> to support the following
    //     because the solutions rapidly become too difficult to implement
    std::vector<double> zeros() const;
    std::vector<double> stationaryPoints() const { return derivative().zeros();}

private:
    std::array<double,2> coeffs;
}
```

My current workaround is to just throw an exception from `Polynomial<N>::zeros()` for `N>2` but it would have been nice to detect the problem at compile-time.

Comment: Is template specialization a possibility for you ?

Comment: If C++11 is available, you can use `static_assert(N <= 2, "Incorrect template argument.")` instead of `throw`. It prevents undesirable function in compile time.

Comment: You need specializations anyways (due to `Polynomial<N-1>`)

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes. `Polynomial<0>::derivative` can't be defined as declared in my example. But how to do it? How do I omit some member functions from some template instantiations? Can I declare them but not define them?

Comment: That is fundamental, a specialized class is an entire different class, and you can use any template without knowing that template before instantiation.

Comment: @DieterLücking Oh ok thanks. I thought it was only possible to specialize the implementations/definitions of the member functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CRTP to implement `zeros` and `zero` in a base class that knows about the derived one.

Then conditionally derive from one that has `zeros` and/or `zero`, or not.

```
template<class P>
struct zeros { /* todo */ };

template<class P>
struct zero:zeros<P> { /* todo */ };

struct nozero {};

template<int N>
struxt Polynomial:
  std::conditional_t<
    (N==1),
    zero<Polynomial<N>>,
    std::conditional_t<
      (N==2),
      zeros<Polynomial<N>>,
      nozero
    >
  >
{
  // body
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `std::enable_if` to SFINAE away the zero function.

```
template< int I >
class Poly {

public:
    template<int Ib = I, typename = std::enable_if_t<Ib == 1> > 
    double zero() 
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Poly< 10 > does_not_compile;
    does_not_compile.zero();

    //Poly< 1 >  compile;
    //compile.zero();
}
```

Comment: This is technically an ill formed program, no diagnostic required.

Comment: Why ? What rules am I breaking ?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is template specialization, in this case, full specialization.

However, I think you would need to think about your design. Generally, it is not a good idea to define different interfaces for different cases because you are not taking advantage of the abstraction.

For example, think about your stationaPoints() function. This functions should not be available for Polynomial<2> because the derivative is a Polynomial<1> which does not have the zeros() function. Your solution is to add the zeros function to the Polynomial<1> in order to homogenize the interface.

For your case, I guess you would like a solution which includes a N-1 c-vector inside the polynomial type with the zeros and a zero(i) function to get them. Something like this:

```
template <int N>
class Polynomial {
    double _coefs[N+1];
    double _zeros[N];
public:
    double zero(size_t i) const { assert(i<N); return _zeros[i]; }
    // ...
};
```

In this case, you could decide the strategy to calculate de zeros, depending on your application: constructor?, adding a boolean to know if it has been calculated then it is calculated in the first call to zero, etc...

I guess this solution could be more interesting for you because if you prefer a c-vector to store the coeficients, you wouldn't like the vector based interface of your zeros() function, would you?

Comment: `Polynomial<N>` in my question is a polynomial of order N, meaning it has N+1 coefficients. Would you mind revising your answer?

Comment: Also, can you suggest a better design? My current solution does store an array of coefficients; I will edit the question to show it.